# Getting the actual, floating-point width of an element

Tags: jquery, css, floating-point, width

I'm using jQuery (v1.7.1) and I need to get the absolute, floating-point width of an element, but all of jQuery's width methods seem to be rounding-off the value of the width.

For example if the actual width of an element was `20.333333px`, jQuery's width method returns `20`, i.e ignoring the decimal value.

You can see what I mean on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MBj/1/)

So, my question is: How do I get the floating-point value of the width of an element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do not round .width() in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603065/do-not-round-width-in-jquery)

Comment: Might want to check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected Seems the browser truncates the pixels, so it's probably not an issue with your jquery.

Comment: jquery width function always return int value hence you will never get a float value. see - http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Thank you @JohnKoerner, I couldn't find that question before, but I am still wondering if there could be any possible solution to this? Some way to retrieve the floating-point width of an element, since the CSS property does seem to be holding it (At-least when I inspect with Chrome's console)

Comment: @MichaelPeterson, thank you, http://jsfiddle.net/q5BQs/3/ pretty much shows that the decimal values are completely ignored when rendering the elements, although those values are retained on Chrome's console.

Comment: When something is displayed, it can ONLY be displayed on a whole pixel boundary.  There is no such thing as a half pixel width.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you already have a reference to the DOM element, [`element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) will get you the values you want.

The method has existed since Internet Explorer 4, and so it's safe to use everywhere. However, the `width` and `height` attributes exist only in IE9+. You have to calculate them if you support IE8 and below:

```
var rect = $("#a")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

var width;
if (rect.width) {
  // `width` is available for IE9+
  width = rect.width;
} else {
  // Calculate width for IE8 and below
  width = rect.right - rect.left;
}
```

`getBoundingClientRect` is 70% faster than `window.getComputedStyle` in Chrome 28, and the differences are greater in Firefox: http://jsperf.com/getcomputedstyle-vs-getboundingclientrect

Comment: According to Mozilla Network Developer : getBoundingClientRect() was introduced since ie4 but `width` and `height` properties were only introduced on ie9. So for ie8 you have to compute it `top - bottom` and `right - left`. Nothing important just to be completely accurate.

Comment: @Ghetolay, I hadn't realized that; thanks for pointing it out. I'll add clarification to my answer.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for ie9. In ie9 getBoundingClientRect returns rounded values, rather than the floating point width the asker wanted. The only way to get an accurate value in ie9 is using getComputedStyle. https://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/z6bx2moh/

Comment: @Ghetolay - minor correction, it should be `bottom - top` for height else you'll end up with a negative number.

Comment: @jools Can you have a look to this updated Fiddle and help me if you know how to do this ? thx. https://jsfiddle.net/z6bx2moh/18/
I am trying to get the floating-point width of an element with dynamic width and that is overflowed...

Comment: @M'sieurToph' `#inner` needs to be `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`. If you can't change that, you'll need to add another wrapper div, inside `#inner` and around your items, which has one of those `display` values. https://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/z6bx2moh/21/

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("a");
alert(window.getComputedStyle(element).width);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/Z2MBj/18/

Comment: Yes, I see, the computed width is rounded (http://jsfiddle.net/Z2MBj/19/ at-least on Chrome). http://jsfiddle.net/q5BQs/3/ shows that more visually.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` is up to 70% faster than `getComputedStyle` and provides the same dimensions: http://jsperf.com/getcomputedstyle-vs-getboundingclientrect

Comment: To add to @ssorallen's comment, `getComputedStyle` returns a string where as `getBoundingClientRect` returns a float.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` does not return the same value as `getComputedStyle`, if the element is affected by any CSS transformations then `getBoundingClientRect` will return the transformed value.

Comment: In IE9 `getBoundingClientRect` returns rounded values and `getComputedStyle` returns the floating point values (once passed through `parseFloat`) to get rid of the "px". jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/z6bx2moh

Comment: for what it's worth, I just ran a few benchmarks in chrome and `getComputedStyle()` was faster than `getBoundingClientRect()`