# HTML5 Canvas: Why does measuring text with measureText and offsetWidth() give different values?

Tags: html, canvas

I benchmarked offsetWidth() vs measureText and I am getting drastically different values. Shouldn't they be the same? Why are they different?

Here is the jsfiddle and raw code below:
http://jsfiddle.net/WhGk7/2/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<span id="visibilityHack" style="visibility: hidden; font: 15px Arial;">textAlign=start</span>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// Create a red line in position 150
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.moveTo(150,20);
ctx.lineTo(150,170);
ctx.stroke();
var measureTextWidth = ctx.measureText("textAlign=start").width;
var measureTextNode =  document.createTextNode("measureTextWidth: " + measureTextWidth);
document.getElementById("results").appendChild(measureTextNode);

var swidth = document.getElementById("visibilityHack").offsetWidth;
var textnode = document.createTextNode("     offsetWidth: " + swidth);
document.getElementById("results").appendChild(textnode);


ctx.font="15px Arial";    

// Show the different textAlign values
ctx.textAlign="start";      
ctx.fillText("textAlign=start",117,60);        
ctx.textAlign="center";     
ctx.fillText("textAlign=start",150,120);
</script>
```

Comment: The actual answer to why the widths are different (in the jsfiddle in the question) is that, as answered by ToddK below, you need to set `ctx.font` *before* doing `measureText`. If I fix that, then I get `measureTextWidth: 95.4638671875 offsetWidth: 95` so canvas measureTextWidth is actually more precise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The support for [context.measureText](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-measuretext) is very bad in most browsers. But there is a hack which allows you to get a much better measurement of text. Create a `<div>` node in your HTML document with `visibility: hidden` (so it isn't rendered) but not `display: none` (so it takes up space). Then set its style to the same style you want to use for `context.fillText` (remember that when you use an external font, that font must be fully loaded to get an accurate measurement), put your text into the div, and check the div's `.width`

Comment: So the only 100% accurate way to measure cross browser is to do the visibility hack?

Comment: @yoshyosh Currently I am afraid it is, but I would be glad to hear of a better solution, because I am currently using it in a project of mine and I am not so happy about it either (although it works perfectly for my purpose).

Comment: I've been relying on measureText for my word wrap algorithm, might have to change that :( @philipp

Comment: I'm comparing values from measureText and this visibility hack, and they're the exact same on Chrome. So this doesn't fix the issue of measureText giving different values on different browsers for me.

Comment: @yoshyosh No need to use the "visibility hack" (anymore), [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27182998/2228771).

Comment: @Domi that doesn't work for me with the latest microsoft edge.  i've resorted `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18341704/895309

Comment: @thecoolmacdude I updated the link. But I am unsure if my statement from 2013 is still correct.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the font on the canvas context before you do measureText, otherwise you will get whatever the default font style is on the context. You already set the font family and size on the hack div and that is why it is giving you the correct value.

What I did observe though is that Chrome 34 and Firefox 28 both returned 92 for the width, but IE10 returned 95, Grrr.

Answer (score 7):

Canvas support was less accurate in the past.

As of November 2014, most browsers seem to work just fine. Tested Chrome, IE and Firefox. Also note that most browsers' `Canvas.measureText` functions even yield results with sub-pixel accuracy. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNzjZ/35/) for reference.

To save you the trouble of writing your own, [you might want to use an existing string-measuring function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/2228771).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that both measureText and "DOM element method" still do not return real text width.
But context2d.measureText and "OM element method" return very similar values :)
Let's try to measure width of text consisting of single character 'y' and printed with 'italic 90px arial'. You can try it on JSFiddle - i modified the Domi's code http://jsfiddle.net/White_Falkon/a23z6ryL/2/

```
/**
 * Uses canvas.measureText to compute and return the width of the given text of given font in pixels.
 * 
 * @param text The text to be rendered.
 * @param {String} font The css font descriptor that text is to be rendered with (e.g. "14px verdana").
 * 
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript/21015393#21015393
 */
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    // if given, use cached canvas for better performance
    // else, create new canvas
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var oldFont = context.font;
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    context.font = oldFont;
    return metrics.width;
};

function getTextWidthDOM(text, font) {
  var f = font || '12px arial',
      o = $('<span>' + text + '</span>')
            .css({'font': f, 'float': 'left', 'white-space': 'nowrap'})
            //.css({'visibility': 'hidden'})
            .appendTo($('body')),
      w = o.width();

  o.remove();

  return w;
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2 - 100;
var text = 'y';
var font = 'italic 90px Arial';

context.font = font;
context.fillStyle = 'blue';    
context.fillText(text, x, y);      
// get text metrics
var widthUsingDOM = getTextWidthDOM(text, font);
var widthUsingMeasureText = getTextWidth(text, font);

context.font = '20pt Calibri';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillText('(' + widthUsingDOM + 'px wide using DOM)', x, y + 100);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fillText('(' + widthUsingMeasureText + 'px wide using measureText)', x, y + 150);

context.beginPath();
context.rect(x, y-75, widthUsingDOM, 125);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.rect(x, y-75, widthUsingMeasureText, 125);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke();
```

You'll see, that part of 'y' on the right is outside the 'width rectangle'.
Another case, when these measuring methods are incorrect is 'y' printed with 'italic 90px times new roman' - the left part of y is outside of width rectangle. You can try it on the same JSFiddle.

Unfortunately, i don't know if there is a way to measure full width of string.