# Why is the sum width of each item not equal to the total in canvas textmetrics

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The width of character `1` is 8.8984375.

So I think 10 characters width is 88.984375, but it is actually 78.296875.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '16px/16px arial';
let per = ctx.measureText('1').width;
let num = 10;
let total = ctx.measureText('1111111111').width;
console.log(per, total, per * 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I believe this post explains it, and has a workaround for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713716/html5-canvas-why-does-measuring-text-with-measuretext-and-offsetwidth-give-di

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text metrics is complicated especially when fonts are not mono spaced. Some characters are padded when measured on their own. `1` happens to be one of them when using `"arial"`

### Calculating the padding.

#### Assumptions

- A character next to its self (either side) will take up the same width for each
- A string of the same characters at each end will have the same padding.

#### Calculation

For the character "1" we can workout the approximate padding by measuring 2 cases  "111" and "11111". We can then create an expression to define the character width `w`, and the padding `p`.

Thus for the strings...

- "111" the width would be `w * 3 + p = w3`, and
- "11111" the width would be `w * 5 + p = w5`.

We now have two equations with 2 unknowns as we can get `w3` and `w5` using `measureText`.

Solving for p (padding) `p = (15 * (w3 / 3) - (3 * w5)) / 2`
Then w (width of character) is `w = (w3 - p) / 3`

Example

The example calculates the width of 1 between 1 and 1 to ~100th of a pixel width.

```js
const width = str => ctx.measureText(str).width;
const test = (str, calc) => 
    console.log("'" + str + "' width = " + width(str).toFixed(2) + 
                "px, calculated = " + calc.toFixed(2) + 
                "px, dif = " + (calc - width(str)).toFixed(2) + "px");


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '16px arial';
const c = "1";

// calculate padding and width of 1
const w3 = width(c.padStart(3, c));
const w5 = width(c.padStart(5, c));    
const padding = (15 * (w3 / 3) -  3 * w5) / 2;
const w = (w3 - padding) / 3;

// test result
test(c, w + padding);
test(c.padStart(10, c), w * 10 + padding);
test(c.padStart(20, c), w * 20 + padding);

console.log("Width of '"+c+"' is ~" + w.toFixed(2) + "px");
console.log("Padding is ~" + padding.toFixed(2) + "px");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### Other Characters

Not all characters have the padding the example below calculates the padding for numbers and lowercase letters.

```js
const width = str => ctx.measureText(str).width;
const test = (str, calc) => 
    console.log("'" + str + "' width = " + width(str).toFixed(2) + 
                "px, calculated = " + calc.toFixed(2) + 
                "px, dif = " + (calc - width(str)).toFixed(2) + "px");


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '16px arial';
console.log("Font: " + ctx.font);
[..."1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"].forEach(calcWidthFor);

function calcWidthFor(c) {
    const w3 = width(c.padStart(3, c));
    const padding = (15 * (w3 / 3) - (3 * width(c.padStart(5, c)))) / 2;
    const w = (w3 - padding) / 3;
    console.log("Width of '"+c+"' is ~ " + w.toFixed(2) + "px Padding is ~ " + padding.toFixed(2) + "px");
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that only few characters have padding.