# Getting integer box widths instead of decimal values: Math.ceil() doesn't round up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Bootstrap navbar. Inspecting with Chrome DevTools I noticed that this (and other browsers, I suppose) returns decimal box widths instead of integers (i.e. 83.06 instead of 83).

[image: decimal width]

For a pixel-perfect alignment with some other elements I need to 'convert to integer' this number, and to avoid button collapse in 2+ words items I need to 'round up' it: in short, `83.06` should become `84` (and not `83`).

The only way I'm aware of is with JavaScript, so I did this script:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){ // recalculate when resizing window
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) { // only in 'desktop' version(s), smaller devices don't need recalculation
    $('.navbar-nav').find('> li:not(.hidden-sm)').each(function(){
      var width = $(this).children('a').outerWidth(); // for each valid 'li', take its 'a' descendant width
      console.log(width); // watch what happens
      $(this).width(Math.ceil(width)); // change item width with a 'rounded up' value
    })
  }
}).resize();
```

Here is the code snippet ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7eho01n/1/)):

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){ // recalculate when resizing window
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) { // only in 'desktop' version(s)
    $('.navbar-nav').find('> li:not(.hidden-sm)').each(function(){
      var width = $(this).children('a').outerWidth(); // for each valid 'li', take its 'a' descendant width
      console.log(width); // watch what happens
      $(this).width(Math.ceil(width)); // change item width with a 'rounded up' value
    })
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link One<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two, Long</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm"><a href="#">Link Three: too long to fit, hide on small devices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Pretty straight, right? But it doesn't work as expected: items' original widths (`86.05`, `124.17` and `107.7` according to Chrome DevTools) are not always rounded up despite the `Math.ceil()` function and I end up with `86`, `124` and `108` (only the latter is right; the first two items 'collapse' because there is not enough space). Shouldn't `Math.ceil()` always round up? Very weird...

"Ok", I thought, "let's find a workaround": so I swapped `Math.ceil()` with `parseInt()` and add at least `+1` pixel, like this other snippet ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7eho01n/2/)):

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){ // recalculate when resizing window
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) { // only in 'desktop' version(s)
    $('.navbar-nav').find('> li:not(.hidden-sm)').each(function(){
      var width = $(this).children('a').outerWidth(); // for each valid 'li', take its 'a' descendant width
      console.log(width); // watch what happens
      $(this).width(parseInt(width)+1); // change item width with a 'rounded up' value
    })
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link One<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two, Long</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm"><a href="#">Link Three: too long to fit, hide on small devices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Good, buttons don't collapse but... try to resize the window: buttons grow forever, maybe because I'm adding 1 pixel to each iteration: this is worse than before...

Now I am stuck and can't imagine other ways to go: any solution to get integers rounded up without ending with all these crazy results, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery's `.width()` already internally rounds the width values to the closest integer (so: `86.05 => 86` , `124.17 => 124` , `107.7 => 108`).

So the values you retrieve using `.width()` and perform your rounding calculations on, are already integers, and therefor they have no effect whatsoever:)

This can be resolved by using JavaScript's native [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):
*This will return the actual floating-point width (got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341704/3407923)).*

```
var width = $(this).children('a')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

You could leave it at that, but now the `width`s of all those `li`s are always reset, whether they already have been or not.
To prevent that, I used an if-clause to check if the width is ***not already*** an integer, and ***only then*** gets the element actually resized.

This is all you need for that (which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886106/3407923)):

```
if (width%1 !== 0) {$(this).width(Math.ceil(width));}
```

But to be safe I would also remove `.children('a')`, and measure the `li`s themselves:

```
var width = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

*Apparently the `a` automatically fills the entire `li`, but the `li` also auto-scales to the `a`, and since you're performing the `.width()` operation on the `li`, it seems safer and more logical to also check the `width` of that same element.*
*Alternatively, you could set the `width()` of the `a` instead of the `li`.*

See **code snippet** for a demo  (put snippet in "Full page" to test):

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){ // recalculate when resizing window
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) { // only in 'desktop' version(s)
    $('.navbar-nav').find('> li:not(.hidden-sm)').each(function(){
      var width = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width; // for each valid 'li', take its 'a' descendant width
      if (width%1 !== 0) {$(this).width(Math.ceil(width));} // if width isn't already an integer, round up
      console.log(width, 'resize: '+(width%1 !== 0));
    });
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link One<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two, Long</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-sm"><a href="#">Link Three: too long to fit, hide on small devices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c7927ud1/6/**

Comment: @Ivan I made a small update to my answer: I removed `.children('a')` from line `var width = ...;`.