# Alignment of thead in table with custom JS/Jquery off in IE

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

In Chrome the alignments is perfect. When it comes to IE the alignment is barely off.
I have a [working sample on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v8Hy/).

But it seems IE does not like to run the code in fiddler. You may need to cut and paste the code into your own doc.

```
<table class='fix-header'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jim James John</td>
            <td>00001</td>
            <td>BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueEVEN LONGER!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sue</td>
            <td>00002</td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Sue</td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Barb</td>
            <td>00003</td>
            <td>Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Jim</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.fix-header, table, thead, tbody, td, th{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}

table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.fix-header thead {display: block;}

.fix-header tbody{
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.fix-header td, .fix-header th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.fix-header tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #c5eff9;}

.fix-header tbody tr td[colspan="3"]{background-color: red;}
```

JS:

```
var padding = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 ? 17.5 : 18;

$.each($('.fix-header'), function(){
    var table = this;
    $.each($('tbody tr:first', this).children(), function(index){
        $('thead th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')', table).width($(this).width()+padding);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is that .width() does not give back an extract number. Instead I am using this now:

```
$(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
```

This is where I found a solution to my answer:
[How to make jQuery to not round value returned by .width()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603065/do-not-round-width-in-jquery)

Here is all the code.

```
<table class='fix-header'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jim James John</td>
            <td>00001</td>
            <td>BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueEVEN LONGER!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sue</td>
            <td>00002</td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Sue</td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Barb</td>
            <td>00003</td>
            <td>Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Jim</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Jim</td><td>00001</td><td>Blue</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jim</td><td>00001</td><td>Blue</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jim</td><td>00001</td><td>Blue</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jim</td><td>00001</td><td>Blue</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
 .fix-header, table, thead, tfoot,tbody, td, th{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}

table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.fix-header thead, .fix-header tfoot {display: block;}

.fix-header tbody{
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.fix-header td, .fix-header th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.fix-header tbody tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #c5eff9;}

.fix-header tbody tr td[colspan="3"]{background-color: red;}
```

JS:

```
$.each($('.fix-header'), function(){
    var table = this;
    $.each($('tbody tr:first', this).children(), function(index){
        var tdWidth = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        $('thead th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')', table).width(tdWidth);
        $('tfoot th:nth-child('+(index+1)+')', table).width(tdWidth);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps someone else out as well!