# .val() rounding up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of `#value_box` to display `100.5` but it keeps rounding up. Does anyone know what I can do to get it to show the decimal place?

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2w5chp8o/)

```
<input type="text" id="the_box" style="width:100.5px" value="" />
<input type="text" id="value_box" value="" />

//returns 101
$("#value_box").val($("#the_box").css('width').replace('px', ''));
```

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that you can't have half pixels in a screen...jQuery returns the *actual* size, rather than the one specified in css. This is why you will always get `px` from jQuery even if you specify other units.

Comment: I beg to differ. 100.5px and 101px looks different on screen.

Comment: doesn't CSS not allow decimals unless using percentages?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the `val` function.

Comment: @Feek it allows it for non-pixel

Comment: Try it for yourself. Decimal places work. Look for yourself the 101px is slightly larger http://jsfiddle.net/2w5chp8o/2/

Comment: Yes @JCOC611, I see a clear difference. In your example. http://i.imgur.com/EN5faoF.png

Comment: Interestingly: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2w5chp8o/1/ `window.getComputedStyle()` returns `100.5` (Chrome 40.x/Win 8.1).

Comment: @bryan This is likely going to be a difference depending on OS and browser. What are you using? They look the exact same to me. Chrome 40.0.2214.111 on Linux.

Comment: The browser has two options: round to `100px` or to `101px`. It literally cannot display half a pixel. It's not physically possible (unless it uses alpha channels to compute some sort of anti-alias like effect).

Comment: @JCOC611, please stop saying it's not possible, when I literally showed you proof in my previous comment. I am using safari in OS X

Comment: @JCOC611 While what you say is true, the browser can factor in these decimals if you zoom the screen.  And in fact, chrome at least does take this into consideration.  bryan's example fiddle is the same width at 100% zoom but becomes 1 pixel different when zoomed in.

Comment: Zooming for me also shows the difference.

Comment: @JamesMontagne that's definitely true. If there is zoom greater than one, decimals *should* make a difference. In that case it isn't appropriate to round up or down.

Comment: So going back to my question, since I am using scaled elements and I've seen first hand that half a pixel does make a difference, is there a way I get that decimal place in my `val()`?

Comment: This question and its answer currently have some issues so I won't close as duplicate, but this could help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603065/how-to-make-jquery-to-not-round-value-returned-by-width   You could also use the non-jquery way to read it if you want `el.style.width`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `.css('width')` that rounds. There's a lot to `.css` in jQuery beyond `getComputedStyle`. [Comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/06Lu0skv/).

For `.css('width')`, jQuery uses `offsetWidth` [[source]](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.3/src/css.js#L112):

```
val = name === "width" ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.offsetHeight,
```

In CSS, pixels are just another unit, defined to be 1/96 of an inch. There's nothing inherently integral about them. In high-DPI displays, such as mobile screens, newer laptops, and printed media, it makes sense to have fractions of "pixels." But `offsetWidth` is defined to be an integer value [[CSSOM]](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface):

```
readonly attribute long offsetWidth;
```

In this case, where you explicitly set a `width` in the inline style, and you want to get it, one thing you could do is just use plain DOM to get it:

```
$("#the_box")[0].style.width.replace('px', '')
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2w5chp8o/4/)

You can also try using `getBoundingClientRect` [[CSSOM]](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extension-to-the-element-interface) and working backwards through the changes introduced by borders and padding. This method returns a `DOMRect` object with information represented as floating-point numbers [[geometry]](http://www.w3.org/TR/geometry-1/#dom-domrect).

```
$("#the_box")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width - ...
```

Comment: Why do I get a decimal if I use `.css('background-size')` then? http://jsfiddle.net/2w5chp8o/5/ Does `.css('width')` round differently then `.css('background-size')`?

Comment: There's no "hook" that specifies a special routine for handling `.css('background-size')`, so it just returns the value from the computed style. For `width` and `height`, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.3/src/css.js#L337