# how we get element width in decimal using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting the width of element in integer rather than in fraction because my element width is `49.358 px`. But i am getting `50px` using

```
$('lichildren').width()
```

where `liChildren` is my variable
please suggest me any alternate for this issue.

Comment: When an element is shown on screen, the browser rounds the size to the nearest pixel - because the smallest unit of measurement on a monitor is a pixel. 50px is probably what the width of the element is when displayed, so the variable is correct

Answer (score 14):

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603065/how-to-make-jquery-to-not-round-value-returned-by-width) Use the native [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) rather than the style of the element. It was introduced in IE4 and is supported by all browsers:

```
$("#lichildren")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d1j6Lkcc/)

Answer (score 2):

See the following answer to a similar question:

[Getting the actual, floating-point width of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907514/getting-the-actual-floating-point-width-of-an-element)

The accepted answer starts by saying:

If you already have a reference to the DOM element, [element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will get you the values you want.