# jQuery UI rounding width of element when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

When I inspect an element on the page, I see that its width is **83.2 pixels**.

I make it "draggable" with jQuery UI:

```
$el.draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        //$(ui.helper).css('margin', 0); //prevent jumping
        console.log('width:', $(ui.helper).css('width'));
        //console.log('width:', $(ui.helper).width());
        //console.log('width:', $(event.target).css('width'));
    }
});
```

The output to the console after dragging the element is `width: 83px`.
This is causing a line-break in the elements text later on.

Is the jQuery UI rounding the width and height?
How do I get the more accurate value?

Comment: If you're removing the margin, doesn't it make sense that the width is less than it was originally?

Comment: `Math.round($(ui.helper).width());` use this

Comment: Isaac, that's what I thought, too. But the width is not reported correctly, even if I remove that line.
Rejith: I am not looking to round the value. I want to get the precise floating-point width of the element when it is dragged.. But jQueryUI seems to round the width when the element is dragged.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072668/426266

jQueryUI seems to set the width of the element to an integer value when the element is dragged.
Also, $(element).width() will always return a rounded integer value.

I solved the problem like this:

```
$el.draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {

        var width = event.target.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        $(ui.helper).css({
            'width': Math.ceil(width)
        });
    }
});
```

Now there is no longer a line-break in the element when it's dragged.