# jquery width() different result cross browser

Tags: jquery, css, width

I justed noticed jQuery's `width()` gets different results in current chrome and firefox.
Im targeting a `li` element, in the inspector it shows me a width of `108.531px`
Since jQuery's `width()` outputs an integer it should be 109..
But in Chrome this resorts to 108, Firefox logs 109..

I tried it with these attributes:

```
border: none;
outline: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I found this post, but am uncertain if this still is state of the art:

```
$("#container")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
```

[How to make jQuery to not round value returned by .width()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603065/how-to-make-jquery-to-not-round-value-returned-by-width)

Why does jQuery have this inconsistency?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im computing the total width of a horizontal navigation, so in short:  
for each li > totalWidth += li.width()`

Comment: Does `.getBoundingClientRect().width` not return expected result?

Comment: yes it does. i just dont feel comfortable using it since i dont know exactly what it does.. and even then: why would i ever use jquerys width() if it is unreliable?

Comment: If you do not need to use `.width()`, then do not use it? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: thanks for the reference! Wouldnt it make sense for jquery to use the getBoundingClientRect architecture, since it outputs the right value? btw: how do you mark code in a comment here? didnt find it in the help

Comment: _"Wouldnt it make sense for jquery to use the getBoundingClientRect architecture, since it outputs the right value?"_ See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1724 .  _"btw: how do you mark code in a comment here? "_ Surround code with backtick `` characters . You can review source for `.width()` at http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.width